# MATLAB: How do I fix subscripted assignment dimension mismatch?

Tags: matlab

new_img is ==>

```
new_img = zeros(height, width, 3);
```

curMean is like this: `[double, double, double]`

```
new_img(rows,cols,:) = curMean;
```

so what is wrong here?

Comment: Assuming rows and cols are within loops and there are assigned a value and curMean is assigned a value then there should be nothing wrong, curMean is assigned to the z/j ( whichever you want to call it ) part of your multidimensional array.

Comment: rows and cols are each lists of indexes. =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
new_img(rows,cols,:) = curMean;
```

will only work if `rows` and `cols` are scalar values. If they are vectors, there are a few options you have to perform the assignment correctly depending on exactly what sort of assignment you are doing. As [Jonas mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796729/matlab-how-do-i-fix-subscripted-assignment-dimension-mismatch/4796958#4796958), you can either assign values for every pairwise combination of indices in `rows` and `cols`, or you can assign values for each pair `[rows(i),cols(i)]`. For the case where you are assigning values for every pairwise combination, here are a couple of the ways you can do it:

- Break up the assignment into 3 steps, one for each plane in the third dimension:

  ```
  new_img(rows,cols,1) = curMean(1);  %# Assignment for the first plane
  new_img(rows,cols,2) = curMean(2);  %# Assignment for the second plane
  new_img(rows,cols,3) = curMean(3);  %# Assignment for the third plane
  ```

  You could also do this in a for loop as [Jonas suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796729/matlab-how-do-i-fix-subscripted-assignment-dimension-mismatch/4796958#4796958), but for such a small number of iterations I kinda like to use an "unrolled" version like above.
- Use the functions [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) and [REPMAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) on `curMean` to reshape and replicate the vector so that it matches the dimensions of the sub-indexed section of `new_img`:

  ```
  nRows = numel(rows);  %# The number of indices in rows
  nCols = numel(cols);  %# The number of indices in cols
  new_img(rows,cols,:) = repmat(reshape(curMean,[1 1 3]),[nRows nCols]);
  ```

For an example of how the above works, let's say I have the following:

```
new_img = zeros(3,3,3);
rows = [1 2];
cols = [1 2];
curMean = [1 2 3];
```

Either of the above solutions will give you this result:

```
>> new_img

new_img(:,:,1) =

     1     1     0
     1     1     0
     0     0     0

new_img(:,:,2) =

     2     2     0
     2     2     0
     0     0     0

new_img(:,:,3) =

     3     3     0
     3     3     0
     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with such assignments!

```
a=zeros(3);
a([1 3],[1 3]) = 1
a =
     1     0     1
     0     0     0
     1     0     1
```

In other words, you assign all combinations of row and column indices. If that's what you want, writing

```
for z = 1:3
   newImg(rows,cols,z) = curMean(z);
end
```

should get what you want (as [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796729/matlab-how-do-i-fix-subscripted-assignment-dimension-mismatch/4796870#4796870) suggested).

However, if `rows` and `cols` are matched pairs (i.e. you'd only want to assign 1 to elements `(1,1)` and `(3,3)` in the above example), you may be better off writing

```
for i=1:length(rows)
    newImg(rows(i),cols(i),:) = curMean;
end
```

Comment: +1 Good point about matched pairs versus all pairwise combinations.